# помогите тотальному новичку

Tags: javascript

когда я навожу несколько раз на элемент ul то при клике на любой элемент li выводится не конкретный элемент в console.log а дублирвоанное количество равное переходам addEventListener.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.getElementById("ulul");
var lil = [];

function inputLength() {
 return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
 ul.appendChild(li);
 input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
 if (inputLength() > 0) {
  createListElement();
 }



}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
 if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
  createListElement();
 }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);


ul.addEventListener("mouseenter", jonDoneUndode, false);

function jonDoneUndode(){
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("li"),function(test){
test.addEventListener("click", function () {
 console.log(this);
  });
 });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Shopping List</h1>
 <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
 <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
 <button id="enter">Enter</button>
 <ul id = "ulul">
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>fff</li>
  <li>dddd</li>
  <li>cccc</li>
  <li>ggggg</li>
  <li>eeee</li>
 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В чем заключается проблема?

Comment: Ну у вас при каждом "mouseenter" вешается событие "click". Ну и чего вы собственно хотите? Может стоило бы повесить событие 1 раз?

Comment: если выти и сновай зайти на элемент ul n-количество раз то console.log выведет  n - количество раз  выбранный  li элемент который сработал на event click , а мне нужно чтобы выводило только 1 раз тот элемент на который нажимаю

Answer (score 2):

При создании элемента вешайте один для всех класс(item) а в обработчике через таргет находите и выводите.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.getElementById("ulul");
var lil = [];


function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = 'item'; // указываем класс
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";      
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches("li.item")) {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  }
});

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Shopping List</h1>
 <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
 <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
 <button id="enter">Enter</button>
 <ul id = "ulul">
  <li class="item bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li class="item">fff</li>
  <li class="item">dddd</li>
  <li class="item">cccc</li>
  <li class="item">ggggg</li>
  <li class="item">eeee</li>
 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: извиняюсь первое сообщение тут ... выложил видимо в вырезанном контексте ... проблема в том что если вызывать 1 раз то новые добавленные элементы не будут участвовать в этом Listener. ( ps изменил исходный код чтобы было видно что имею ввиду)

Comment: @PavelBogushko, следовательно навешивать надо только на новые, а не на все, которые уже есть на странице. И проще всего это делать в методе. который и создает новые элементы

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за помощь теперь немного больше стал понимать!

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.getElementById("ulul");
var lil = [];

function inputLength() {
 return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
 ul.appendChild(li);
 input.value = "";
 li.addEventListener("click",jonDoneUndone);
}

function jonDoneUndone() {

 console.log(this);
 }

function addListAfterClick() {
 if (inputLength() > 0) {
  createListElement();
 }

}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
 if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
  createListElement();
 }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);


//ul.addEventListener("mouseenter", jonDoneUndode, false);

//function jonDoneUndode(){
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("li"),function(test){
test.addEventListener("click", jonDoneUndone);});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Shopping List</h1>
 <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
 <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
 <button id="enter">Enter</button>
 <ul id = "ulul">
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>fff</li>
  <li>dddd</li>
  <li>cccc</li>
  <li>ggggg</li>
  <li>eeee</li>
 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```